# Wordpress won't let me wrap a div in an anchor tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am in a page template and I'm trying to wrap a whole div in an  tag. I want the whole div element to be clickable, not just two header tag elements. The  tag is being broken apart and cut too soon. nesting problem? I'm not sure - tried a lot of different things. Here is the code... see line `<a href="<?php echo esc_url($education['lightbox']);?>">` is the anchor tag I'm trying to include

```
    <section id="<?php echo esc_attr($menu_id);?>" class="section section-education">
                <div class="animate-up">
                    <?php if($title):?>
                        <h2 class="section-title"><?php echo esc_html($title);?></h2>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if($education_fields):?>
                    <div class="timeline">
                        <div class="timeline-bar"></div>
                        <div class="timeline-inner clearfix myBox">
                            <?php                               
                            $i=0;foreach ($education_fields as $education):
                                    if ($i % 2 == 0):
                                        $class = 'timeline-box-left';
                                        $class_inner = 'animate-right';
                                    else:
                                        $class = 'timeline-box-right';
                                        $class_inner = 'animate-left';                                      
                                    endif;
                            ?> 

                              <a href="<?php echo esc_url($education['lightbox']);?>">
                                <div class="timeline-box timeline-box-compact <?php echo esc_attr($class); ?>">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>

                                    <div class="timeline-box-inner <?php echo esc_attr($class_inner); ?>">
                                        <?php if($education['years']):?>
                                            <span class="arrow"></span>
                                            <div class="date"><?php echo esc_html($education['years']);?></div>
                                        <?php
                                        endif;
                                        if($education['education_name']):
                                            ?>
                                            <h3><?php echo esc_html($education['education_name']);?></h3>
                                        <?php
                                        endif;
                                        if($education['education_place']):
                                            ?>
                                            <h4>
                                            <?php if($education['education_place_link']):?>
                                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url($education['education_place_link']);?>">
                                            <?php endif;?>
                                            <?php echo esc_html($education['education_place']);?>
                                            <?php if($education['education_place_link']):?>
                                                </a>


                                            <?php endif;?>
                                            </h4>
                                        <?php endif;?>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                    <?php if($custom_editor):?>
                        <div class="section-txt-btn"><?php echo $custom_editor;?></div>
                    <?php endif;?>
                </div>
            </section>
```

And this is what is being returned:

```
    <div class="timeline-box timeline-box-compact timeline-box-left" style=""><a href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image">
                                    <span class="dot"></span>

                                    </a><div class="timeline-box-inner animate-right animated"><a href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image">
                                                                                        <span class="arrow"></span>
                        <div class="date">1974 - 1976</div>                                                                                 <h3>High School</h3>
                                                                                        </a><h4><a href="http://johnhoich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/logo-compass-1.png" data-featherlight="image"></a>
```

[Westside](http://whs.westside66.org/)

Comment: @kritikaTalwar: your edit removed some of the code formatting, so I have rejected it. Additionally, you do not need to add bold formatting to code introductions, it does not make things more readable.

Comment: @halfer do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out:

**Solution:**
I put the `<a>` tag at the end of the div/section and added some css: made it absolute, with top, bottom, right, left = to 0, adjusted the width and height accordingly to cover the entire content area along with raising the z-index. This allowed the link to cover, instead of wrap the div.

Answer (score 0):

You have got this link...

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($education['education_place_link']);?>">
```

... inside the DIV that you are wrapping with the `<a>` tag you quoted, but a link inside a link is not possible, it will break the HTML for sure...